# How to search through struct in Spark 2?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following two `DataFrames` in `Spark 2.2.0` and `Scala 2.11.8`.

```
df1 =

+----------+-------------------------------+
|item      |        other_items            |
+----------+-------------------------------+
|  111     |[[444,1.0],[333,0.5],[666,0.4]]|
|  222     |[[444,1.0],[333,0.5]]          |
|  333     |[]                             |
|  444     |[[111,2.0],[555,0.5],[777,0.2]]|
+----------+-------------------------------+
```

The `printScheme` gives the following output:

```
 |-- item: string (nullable = true)
 |-- other_items: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- item: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- rank: double (nullable = true)
```

And:

```
df2 = 

+----------+-------------+
|itemA     | itemB       |
+----------+-------------+
|  111     | 333         |
|  222     | 444         |
|  333     | 555         |
|  444     | 777         |
+----------+-------------+
```

For each pair in `df2`, I want to find `rank` from `df1`. To do this, I should find the same pair in `df1`, so that `df1.item` is equal to `df2.itemA` and `other_items.struct.[item]` is equal to `df2.itemB`. If such pair cannot be found, the rank should be 0.

The result should be this one:

```
+----------+-------------+-------------+
|itemA     | itemB       |  rank       |
+----------+-------------+-------------+
|  111     | 333         |   0.5       |
|  222     | 444         |   1.0       |
|  333     | 555         |   0.0       |
|  444     | 777         |   0.2       |
+----------+-------------+-------------+
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Hey, haters. What's wrong with the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want. The trick is to explode other_items before the join:

```
df2.as("df2").join(
   df1.select($"item", explode($"other_items").as("other_items")).as("df1"),
    $"df2.itemA" === $"df1.item" and $"df2.itemB" === $"df1.other_items.item"
    , "left"
 )
 .select($"itemA", $"itemB", coalesce($"df1.other_items.rank", lit(0.0)).as("rank"))
 .show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your requirement by defining a `udf` function and call that `udf` function after you `join` both `dataframe`s as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def findRank = udf((items: mutable.WrappedArray[String], ranks: mutable.WrappedArray[Double], itemB: String) => {
  val index = items.indexOf(itemB)
  if(index != -1) ranks(index) else 0.0
})
df1.join(df2, df1("item") === df2("itemA"), "right")
    .select(df2("itemA"), df2("itemB"), findRank(df1("other_items.item"), df1("other_items.rank"), df2("itemB")).as("rank"))
  .show(false)
```

you should get `dataframe` as

```
+-----+-----+----+
|itemA|itemB|rank|
+-----+-----+----+
|111  |333  |0.5 |
|222  |444  |1.0 |
|333  |555  |0.0 |
|444  |777  |0.2 |
+-----+-----+----+
```

Comment: I am using Scala.

Comment: This answer is also in Scala. :)

Comment: Is it possible to use `def` in Scala? I didn't know it.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan no, def is used for method definition